# How should I go about reading keyboard inputs for creating a 2D game in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I'm trying to create a 2D game in C# using as a WPF application. My XAML is simply just a `Grid` with an `Image` in which is drawn to in a `CompositionTarget.Rendering` method. How should I got about setting up code to read keystrokes that will be used to move sprites?

As a side objective I'd also like to read a gamepad's input too for the program so I want something that won't cause problems for controller support later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your wpf window:

```
<Window>
   <Window.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding DoSomethingMoveLeftOrSo}"/>
   </Window.InputBindings>
</Window>
```

And in the command you can perform your action

Comment: Regarding your controller issue we cant really help unless you tell us what kind of controller you plan to use

Comment: What do you mean what kind? Any really, controllers made for PC, an Xbox one, Playstation, just any generic game controller.

Comment: They all use different APIs as far as i am aware XBox might work out of the box but they have very different working principles start with the keyboard and add third party support later on

Comment: I've managed to get InputBindings to work but it's only letting me hold one key at a time, if I have something like Left & Up held down then it only executes the last one.